# How to change the default session timeout in Vert.x (java)

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

We want to change the default session timeout in Vert.x. After searching in the documentation I've found that sessions use this variable to define timeout value:

```
public static final long DEFAULT_SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800000L
```

This variable is stored in the class `io.vertx.ext.web.handler.SessionHandler` (Vert.x Web) but we can't find the way or the method to change this value from 30 min to 60 min.

So, how can i change the default session timeout ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long TIMEOUT_IN_MS = 3600000L;

router.route()
  .handler(SessionHandler.create(store).setSessionTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MS));
```

See "[Handling Session](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_handling_sessions)" in the Vert.x Web documentation for more details.